# Merge rows which have the same date within a data frame

Tags: r, date, aggregate

I have a data.frame as follows:

```
         timestamp     index   negative  positive sentiment
            <dttm>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2015-10-29 15:00:10     0       11       10        -1
2 2015-10-29 17:26:48     0        1        5         4
3 2015-10-29 17:30:07     0       10       22        12
4 2015-10-29 20:13:22     0        5        6         1
5 2015-10-30 14:25:26     0        3        2        -1
6 2015-10-30 18:22:30     0       14       15         1
7 2015-10-31 14:16:00     0       10       23        13
8 2015-11-02 20:30:18     0       14        7        -7
9 2015-11-03 14:15:00     0        8       26        18
10 2015-11-03 16:52:30    0       12       34        22
```

I would like to know if there is a possibility to merge rows with equal days such that i have a scoring for each day, since I have absolutely no clue how to approach this problem because I dont even know how to unlist each date and write a function which merges only equal dates, because the time differs in each day . I would like to obtain a data.frame which has the following form:

```
           timestamp     index   negative  positive sentiment                
            <dttm>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
         1 2015-10-29     0       27       43        16
         2 2015-10-30     0        3        2        -1
         3 2015-10-31     0       17       17         0
         4 2015-11-02     0       14        7        -7
         5 2015-11-03     0       20       60        40
```

Is there any possibility to get around to this result? I would be thankful for any hint.

Comment: Look at the `dplyr` package for `group_by()` and `summarise()` functions.  Or `data.table` package making use of the `by = ` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` to do this. Before doing that, you'll need to show that it should sort according to the day, ignoring the exact time-point.

I will assume you have your data stored as `df`:

```
aggregate(df[ ,2:5], FUN="sum", by=list(as.Date(df$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked out perfect